# Minimalistic Visual C++ app which shows a window

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-c++-2010, crt

I'm trying to create a C++ application in Visual Studio 2010 which matches the following criteria:

1. Displays an empty window
2. Is small as possible (say, under
   100kb)
3. Runs on fresh empty install of Windows XP (does not
   require any runtimes, libraries, etc)

Basically, I want to get rid of runtime. The only thing I need is to call WinAPI functions to display a window and BitBlt something to it's surface.

Is it possible?

Comment: http://www.paulgriffiths.net/program/c/srcs/winhellosrc.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1/2:** Visual Studio can generate a bare-bones template, which is exactly what you need (displays an empty window). Use `File -> New -> New Project -> select 'Win32 Project' -> click 'Finish'` to create the project. The Release\Win32 binary is 81KB when statically linking to the C run-time library (more on this below). Of course, adding your code will likely increase the binary size. You may want to look at optimization settings or even [binary compression](http://upx.sourceforge.net/) to minimize size. The latter I would not recommend due to frequent false positives from anti-virus software.

**3:** You will need to statically link to the [C run-time library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/abx4dbyh%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). This can be configured under `Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Code Generation -> Runtime Library` (select `/MT` for release and `/MTd` for debug). Doing so will allow you to run the executable without the presence of the [Visual C++ 2010 redistributable package](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=8328) installation.

Note that binaries compiled with Visual Studio 2010 require Windows XP SP2 or higher. You may wish to check [this workaround](http://forums.winamp.com/showpost.php?p=2802963&postcount=474) if you need to target pre-SP2 versions of Windows XP.

Answer (score 3):

[The MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384843.aspx) has a nice step-by-step example of WinAPI "Hello, World!". You just need to take a bit of kefir and get into it ;)